# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Stripe\Customer as array

Tags: php, stripe-payments

When I am **creating stripe customer** it is giving me the error that i mentioned.

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Stripe\Customer as array**

```
include("vendor/autoload.php");

use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Customer;

Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_Gq0THSZXNnpOqFRpN4uSwV7Y");


if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_anjsdanjnasdjnjads");
$sEmail=$_POST['stripeEmail'];
$sToken=$_POST['stripeToken'];
    $customer = Customer::create(array(
        "email" => $sEmail,
        "source" => $sToken,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the **latest** version of **Stripe API** which as it turns out to be unstable. ***Downgraded*** to version **4.2** and it worked !